# Active user account from 2004 to 2007 no longer found

Tags: support, deleted-users, merge-accounts

An associate is trying to login with her account from "way back", and her username seems to no longer exist- in fact, she created a new account with the same username as before and was allowed to create it.

Is there a reason the old account might have been dropped, and is there a way to get it restored?

Comment: Usernames are not reserved in our system. She would need to know the login method (which OpenID service) she used when she created the previous account. Does the account show up when she searches for it by name on the [Users page](http://stackoverflow.com/users)? Also, Stack Overflow didn't exist until 2008.

Comment: hot dam that's some downvotage!

Answer (score 10):

As animuson points out in his comment:

1. User names on Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange in general) are not unique.
2. Stack Overflow didn't exist in 2004. It was started in 2008.

However, assuming you are talking about an account on Stack Overflow there are circumstances where an account might be deleted:

1. It was deemed to be a spam account. Then it would be destroyed by moderator action. I am assuming that this is unlikely in this case.
2. The account was inactive. See [this question on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48262/when-will-inactive-accounts-be-deleted) and [this blog post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/02/when-is-an-account-abandoned/) for the full details, but inactive means that the user hasn't visited the site in 6 months and has less than 50 reputation points.

Regardless of this your associate can just create a new account and use that from now on. If it turns out the original account wasn't deleted and is rediscovered then the accounts can be merged - just use the "contact us" form linked to in the footer.

Comment: Also, Boomhauer; I took a guess at what that associate's account might be; an account partially named "An...er". There does not appear to be any other account existing now with that name. (I tried with and without a space in the middle). So either the original account was deleted, or it was under a different name.

Comment: "An...er" looks like "Andrew Barber", so are you the nuked user @Andrew? :D

Comment: @Infi Ack! Hah!

Comment: an...er is correct. She's now thinking it may have been another site ;) experts-exchange maybe? thanks for the help, we'll keep trying to figure it out.